# I tried to make ListView and get the data from string, but got this error

Tags: java, android, string, listview

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/macos/Documents/SubmissionExpert1/app/src/main/res/layout/data.xml","position":{"startLine":11}}],"original":"/Users/macos/Documents/SubmissionExpert1/app/src/main/res/layout/data.xml:12: AAPT: error: resource string/name_heroes (aka com.example.submissionexpert1:string/name_heroes) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/macos/Documents/SubmissionExpert1/app/src/main/res/layout/data.xml","position":{"startLine":20}}],"original":"/Users/macos/Documents/SubmissionExpert1/app/src/main/res/layout/data.xml:21: AAPT: error: resource string/lorem (aka com.example.submissionexpert1:string/lorem) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource linking failed
  >    /Users/macos/Documents/SubmissionExpert1/app/src/main/res/layout/data.xml:12: AAPT: error: resource string/name_heroes (aka com.example.submissionexpert1:string/name_heroes) not found.

  /Users/macos/Documents/SubmissionExpert1/app/src/main/res/layout/data.xml:21: AAPT: error: resource string/lorem (aka com.example.submissionexpert1:string/lorem) not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
20 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 16 up-to-date

Comment: Looks like you do not have the following string in your `strings.xml` file - `string/name_heroes`

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you don't have the file called `data.xml` in `layout` or you need to configure your `sourceSets` for resources in your build.gradle.

Something along these lines in your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'app/main/res'
        }
    }
}
```